# Remove the "via {hosting_server_name}" link that shows up on Gmail when sending out system generated notifications (DailyRazor)

Tags: php, gmail, sendmail, joomla1.5, phpmailer

So, I have been trying to figure this one out for a few weeks without any luck.

I have an old Joomla 1.5 site hosted on DailyRazor, current code makes use of phpMailer which is wrapped by Joomla's own framework. Here's the thing: Every time the site sends out an automated email, there is a "via ldz3.dailyrazor.com" link that shows up next to the sender's email as shown below:

```
{senderName} {senderEmail} via ldz3.dailyrazor.com
```

The "via" word, has a link to this Google [article](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=en&ctx=mail).

Anyway. I've created plenty of SPF records, using online tools, replicating solutions that some bloggers have posted (replacing server and dns information, of course) and even opened several tickets hoping their tech support would help me out with no luck.

I have other Joomla sites that use similar code and such link never appears on emails.